# libcrypt.so vs libcrypto.so, what's the difference?

Tags: c, linux

I am reading some package files of Ubuntu and find that [`libc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libc6) depends on [`libcrypt1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libcrypt1). `libcrypt1` contains these files (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libcrypt1/filelist):

> ```
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1.1.0
> /usr/share/doc/libcrypt1/changelog.Debian.gz
> /usr/share/doc/libcrypt1/copyright
> ```

while `libcrypto.so` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libssl1.1/filelist) is installed by [`libssl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libssl1.1), which I think belongs to [`openssl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openssl) (correct me if I am wrong)?

So what's the difference between `libcrypt.so` and `libcrypto.so`?

I am more familiar with `libcrypto.so` for which I know it provides some TLS layer functionalites.

What functionality does `libcrypt.so` provide?

Google doesn't give any reuslts while indicating that `libcrypt.so` is kinda useless and deprecated?

Answer (score 8):

they're unrelated

`libcrypt`:

> Description-en: libcrypt shared library
> libxcrypt is a modern library for one-way hashing of passwords.
> It supports DES, MD5, NTHASH, SUNMD5, SHA-2-256, SHA-2-512, and
> bcrypt-based password hashes
> It provides the traditional Unix 'crypt' and 'crypt_r' interfaces,
> as well as a set of extended interfaces like 'crypt_gensalt'.

symbols provided by `libcrypt` (at least on my host):

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so | grep ' T ' | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u | xargs
crypt crypt_checksalt crypt_gensalt crypt_gensalt_r crypt_gensalt_ra crypt_gensalt_rn crypt_preferred_method crypt_r crypt_ra crypt_rn encrypt encrypt_r fcrypt setkey setkey_r xcrypt xcrypt_gensalt xcrypt_gensalt_r xcrypt_r
```

`libcrypto` is the openssl cryptography routines

Comment: Suggest you leave out the `| xargs` so make the list of symbols easier to read.

Comment: Thanks. Is `libcrypt` still widely used today? Does `libcrypto` use `libcrypt` ?

Comment: @AllanWind it's 20 lines of stuff that doesn't matter -- the xargs was intentional

Comment: @AnthonySottile Sorry, but I do not understand that.  You dig out symbols from a library (which is cool btw) but then you don't want the reader to be able to see the information?  What did you want the reader to learn from it then?